# HOW? web hosting one FTP account with multiple user account?

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

My webhosting service provide me one FTP account. and user/client connect with their own id and password and access to the file on ftp on its own directories?
or simple word. how do i create multiple user for accessing thier directories on ftp?
The site is coded on php.
server apache

Answer (score 0):

do the users only go though the web interface? if so create a directory for then and sanitize the inputs with php so they cannot browse under the base tree you give them.

Comment: No there is the device which have only interact with ftp port. only the site is for create account.